# Weighted Least Squares weights not changing Jacobian matrix

Tags: regression, least-squares, jacobian

I currently have 4 data points and the following Jacobian matrix $A$ and cost vector $b$

$
A
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   -0.7867 &    0.0464&   -0.6155 &  1.0000 \\ 
   -0.3751 &   0.4299 &  -0.8213  &  1.0000 \\
    0.0447 &   0.4895 &  -0.8708  &  1.0000 \\
   -0.5946 &   0.8029 &   0.0424  &  1.0000 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$b = \begin{bmatrix}
    26.3019 \\
        1.1 \\
    4.4677 \\
    4.6455 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I am trying to use weighted least squares with the following equation to reduce the effect of the 1st data point.

$H = (A^TWA)^{-1}A^TW$ so that $y = Hb$

However my weighted Jacobian matrix $H$ seems to be virtually the same regardless of what weights I put in.

$W_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
   1 &   0&   0 &  0 \\ 
   0 &   1 &  0  &  0 \\
   0 &   0 &  1  &  0\\
   0 &   0 &   0  &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$H_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
   0.4964 &   -3.4382&    2.8939&    0.0479\\
   -2.4944&    4.2279 &  -2.2013&    0.4678\\
    1.2034&   -3.8577&    1.6862&    0.9681\\
    2.2469&   -5.2755&    3.4167&    0.6119\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$W_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
   .0001 &   0&   0 &  0 \\ 
   0 &   1 &  0  &  0 \\
   0 &   0 &  1  &  0\\
   0 &   0 &   0  &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$H_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
   0.4964 &   -3.4382&    2.8939&    0.0479\\
   -2.4944&    4.2279 &  -2.2013&    0.4678\\
    1.2034&   -3.8577&    1.6862&    0.9681\\
    2.2469&   -5.2755&    3.4167&    0.6119\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Is there a reason why my weights have no effect on the Jacobian and are there requirements on the Jacobian matrix or the weights of Weighted Least Squares? For the weight matrix $W$, should it be $w^Tw$ for a 4x1 weight vector instead of a diagonal matrix?

Comment: From the equation listed here(https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/352) and in the answer below, shouldn't there be a W at the end of the H equation?

Comment: I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply because $A$ is a square and non-singular matrix. Therefore,
\begin{align}
H = (A^TWA)^{-1}A^TW = A^{-1}(A^TW)^{-1}A^TW = A^{-1}.
\end{align}
In practice, $A$ is typically slim rectangular ($n\times p$ with $n > p$) so $(A^TWA)^{-1}$ cannot be written to $A^{-1}(A^TW)^{-1}$ thus $W$ would have effect.

Comment: As a follow-up is there a way to weigh scenarios where you have square matrices?

Comment: As long as the design matrix is non-singular, then as the calculation in the answer shows, there is no way (the effect of $W$ cancelled with each other).